# C++ Vector sorting program

Tags: c++, void

Would somebody help me how to sort in vectors in void in alphabetical way

```
void SortCAR(vector<CAR>vec)
{
}
```

This have to be filled. I think i should put loop

```
    struct CAR{
    string marka;
    string model;
    int year;
    int cubatura;
    int power;
    float price;
};

void InputCAR(vector<CAR> & vec)
```

These are my variables if this can help.

Comment: You want to sort the vector by `model`?

Comment: I think this may be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476926/for-c-sort-how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-custom-compare-function